# Images in dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi I want to put image along with some data in asp.net drop down list box.

Can somebody give me a sample code to achieve this functionality?

country flag + country name --> in the same list item

Answer (score 19):

You could use **jQuery Image Dropdown**:

http://marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

[image: jQuery Image Dropdown]
<sub>(source: [marghoobsuleman.com](http://marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/customdropdown/icons/preview.gif))</sub>

```
<script language="javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    try {
        // target some ids
        MSDropDown.init("#combo1, #combo2");
        //by wild card
        MSDropDown.init("#divid select");
        //or 
        MSDropDown.init("#formid select");
    } catch(e) {
    alert(e);
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to use this [JQuery Combo-Box,](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) but from the screenshot, it looks like the items in the combo box can include an image in it. Maybe you could research more regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

With standart dropdownlist, you can not achive this.

You need to write a custom server control that is not based on dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with a raw drop down list / combo box in C#.  The underlying control only supports text and not a combination of text + image.

You'll either need to write a custom control or use something like jQuery to build the drop down with your code populating the results.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, standard tool doesn't accept images, try with a custom tool.

try with this free tool: http://controlsbuilder.com/tools/CustomDropDownList.aspx