# How can I show just the icon of the currently selected option?

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

Is it possible to have a bunch of `<select>` dropdowns in html that only display a small (say 10 pixels wide) icon, but when you click it the drop down has a list with the icons beside a descriptive string.  (Let's see if ASCII art works on SO):

```
[X]
| X - Disable |
| v/ - Enable |
| O - Ignore  |
+-------------+
[O]
[v]
[X]
```

Can that be done in CSS?  Or in jQuery?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079112/images-in-dropdown-list

Comment: heh, the duplicate even found the same plugin I did.  What he said :)

Comment: @Thomas, no it's not a dup because I don't want the text to show for the selected one.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible with a `<select>` tag in HTML. You'd need to use a custom control provided perhaps with a jQuery plugin. Either way, the entire thing would have to be Javascript and probably wouldn't make use of `<select>` at all. You could also take a look at [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com) if you wanted a set of more fully-featured rich controls. It has a [Menu](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.menu.Menu) class you could use for this.

Comment: You would need to have an actual select in there too, for accessability and backwards compability.  You can then replace it with javascript generated control.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it using jquery.  Marghoob Suleman’s [Javascript Combo Box](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/jquery-image-dropdown-2.1/index.html) plugin for jquery looks like what you want.

[image: image dropdown]

It looks like you want a combination of this dropdown with some code similar to [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403303/how-can-i-show-just-the-icon-of-the-currently-selected-option/2403367#2403367) - so that only the image is shown unless the dropdown is active.

Comment: Very nice. I've never used this one before.

Comment: No, I don't want to show the text of the selected one, only the icon.

Comment: but you could add javascript to change the css of the selected option… attach to the `OnChange` event, put your option text in a span, change css of selected `span` to `display: none` bam. This will work.

Comment: Note: using invisible spans actually doesn't work in *real* option elements.

Comment: I'd feel a lot happier about this plugin if the links on the guy's page actually worked.  He's got a link to version 2.1 on his home page that's broken, and so are all the Javascript links from his "Components and Modules" page.

Comment: The links are indeed dead. I could however get a copy by just checking the page source of the demo page and following the URL to the JS: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/jquery-image-dropdown-2.1/msdropdown/js/jquery.dd.js

Comment: @BalusC - I tried that, and I get an error that Firebug won't actually show me where it is.  I'd much rather get a non-minified version, or have some indication that the developer is actually alive and cares about the plugin.

Comment: The page is still in the google cache (http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:igyT0q7ov18J:www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown%3F%26utm_source%3Dreferrer%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_term%3Djunior%26utm_content%3Dsuleman%26utm_campaign%3Draghib+marghoobsuleman.com+dropdown&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a) so I guess it's a recent break

Answer (score 1):

The show/hide part can be done with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com). Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2403303</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('select')
                    .bind('mouseover', function() { $(this).addClass('expand').removeClass('clicked'); })
                    .bind('click', function() { $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); })
                    .bind('mouseout', function() { if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { $(this).removeClass('expand'); }})
                    .bind('change blur', function() { $(this).removeClass('expand clicked'); });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            select { font-family: monospace; width: 35px; }
            select.expand { width: auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select><option>X - Disable</option><option>V - Enable</option><option>O - Ignore</option></select><br>
        <select><option>X - Disable</option><option>V - Enable</option><option>O - Ignore</option></select><br>
        <select><option>X - Disable</option><option>V - Enable</option><option>O - Ignore</option></select><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [it doesn't work in MSIE](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/348742/feature-request-background-image-for-elements), but you can do it with CSS:

```
select#dropdown option[value="disable"] {
    background-image:url(disable.png);
}
```