# Is there a dropdown listbox that uses pictures instead of text?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, web-frameworks

In my web application, I need to let users (mostly IE browsers) to click on a dropdown listbox and instead of listing a bunch of text. I want to show a list of graphics. How do I go about this?

Comment: i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079112/images-in-dropdown-list um... i couldn't find any a while ago. must have typed the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this it has images and text.  I'm sure you could modify it to be only images.

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown