# change paypal dropdown to images

Tags: html, css, forms, paypal

My paypal form is:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
             <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BZDFVPOK8XKQ">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <select name="os0">
                    <option>Please Select</option>
                      <option value="small">small</option>
                      <option value="medium">medium</option>
                      <option value="large">large</option>

                </select>
          <input type="image" src="images/buyitnow.png"  style="width:100px; height:30px; padd" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
            </form>
```

I want to change the drop down menu into 3 images S, M, L so the user can select an image instead of having to select from dropdown. is this possible

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079112/images-in-dropdown-list

Comment: no, i dont want the drop down menu at all, just an 3 images side by side then the user clicks on the image and then clicks buy it now

Comment: Well, paypal may be only accepting a dropdown menu...  I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need radio buttons instead of a drop down menu !

Use CSS to display each radio button as an image. You might need some javascript too.

---

Try this plugin http://www.thheuer.com/2011/10/jquery-plugins-image-radio-buttons/

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Here's how to use paypal's radio buttons: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside (look at the bottom).

Comment: Yes, and instead of text, include the image between `<option type="radio" ...></option>` tags.

Comment: i cant get this to work, can you make a jsfiddle if possible please