# 3 image in dropdown and custom control it

Tags: c#

Im new to this forum n new in c# world too, i got this question:

How to draw 3 image in one dropdown item , I got this code from this site

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/combobox-with-images/

I want to add 3 image like this [see image below] in my dropdown control and I got control of those image too like when dropped and click the image it'll do something, or something like that

example image : http://i59.tinypic.com/2viftyf.jpg

Is it possible to make it ? Sorry for my english

Thanks for answer n replay.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class, which inherits from the drop-down class and override it's paint function (but this is a bit too advanced).

If you are using ASP.NET you could take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079180/3902603).
If you are using WinForms, you have to override the paint-function. You could take a look at this post: [Placing Images and Strings with a C# Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080719/placing-images-and-strings-with-a-c-sharp-combobox)

**Edit** (after your second comment)**:**

If I understand it correctly you must change those lines:

```
if (item.ImageIndex != -1)
{
    imageList.Draw(ea.Graphics, bounds.Left, bounds.Top, item.ImageIndex);

    ea.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, ea.Font, new
        SolidBrush(ea.ForeColor), bounds.Left+imageSize.Width, bounds.Top);
}
```

into this:

```
// some code

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    imageList.Draw(ea.Graphics, bounds.Left + i * imageSize.Width, bounds.Top, i);
    //            your graphics, left offset + i * image width,   top offset, image index

ea.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, ea.Font, new
SolidBrush(ea.ForeColor), bounds.Left + 4 * imageSize.Width, bounds.Top);
//                           adjust left string offset here

// some code
```

Comment: I already take a look into those thread, but what I want isn't something like that {please look into picture link} , and again I m not using html or such thing , i'm using pure C# for my program. Any other suggest ?

Comment: As my understanding from maxscript user view, 
``
imageList.Draw(ea.Graphics, bounds.Left, bounds.Top,
item.ImageIndex);``


code taken from http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/combobox-with-images/

I just have to add for loop before imageListxxxx.... and close it. but I don't know how to do it with 3 image on the horizontal position like in my example image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using `html`?

Html DropDowns, which are `select` tags, doesn't support his type of customization. You can "fake" this ui by using other html tags and make them look like dropdowns, for example `<ul><li>` tags.

There are plugins which does this for you, like [kendo dropdowns](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template)

Comment: @ RaraituL : no im not, im try to implement it on my own prog, no html , pure c#.

Thanks